# SQLSTATE[42S22] : Laravel self naming columns

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've started a new project for my school so i am really beginner on Laravel.

My laravel seems to guessing table names instead of me. When i try to get some data using postman, it says;

"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'teachers.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from teachers where teachers.id = 5 limit 1)".

But "teachers.id" is not my column name. Its "Teacher_ID" but it guesses instead of me.

This might be hilariously easy problem but im really beginner on laravel.

Edit.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMtVQ.png) - [Routes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thTBI.png) - [Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PazbO.png) - [Table Migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40tT0.png) - [Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nj7Qu.png) - [Resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXLtg.png)

Comment: paste your code in your question

Comment: in your model class add this line. `protected $primaryKey = 'Teacher_ID';`

Comment: @AfrazAhmad Thanks god it works with your code. But what if the column is not a primarykey, what can i do on that situation. How to specify column like that or is this spesific for primary keys ?

Comment: Eloquent expects the primary key to be `id`, so when you use `Model::find()`, that's what it will look for, unless you override it by setting the `primaryKey`. The only other fields it will expect certain names are the timestamps and relationship keys, which you can also override. Anything else will look for what you tell it.

Comment: There aren't many times that Laravel guesses at column names, but some are primary keys (like in your issue), local keys, foreign keys (both on relationships, like `->belongsTo()`, etc.). So I wouldn't worry about that unless you come across it.

Comment: Using 'id' as a primary key is a very good practice. Take it, and you will avoid many unnecessary problems in the future.

Comment: You guys are the best! I wish you happy programming and god bless my friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**By Dafault Laravel will consider id column as PRIMARY KEY**

But if it is different then you can use:

```
 protected $primaryKey = 'primary_key_column';
```

To avoid such kind of issue, always use `id` as primary column.

Laravel also guesses the table names, local keys and foreign keys when you call a relationship. If your keys are not what laravel is expecting then you can tell laravel which key to find.

**Laravel guess table as plural of its model class name.**

If model class is `User` then laravel will guess table name as `users`
If your table is different then use this line.

```
protected $table = 'your_table_name';
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I wish you happy programming sessions :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. Same to you :)